# Windows Server 2012 R2 configure as wifi access point / router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I have a windows server at home which handles all DNS and DHCP for my network. Recently my upstairs router exploded and I need to find a new way of providing Wifi for my home. The server has a new Wifi card in it currently and I thought why not use the server as an access point.

My network ip range is 10.1.1.0/24 with the server's IP being 10.1.1.2 and the gateway's being 10.1.1.1. The problem comes when I try and configure netsh hostednetwork none of my devices can connect to the internet or see any other device on the lan. The server can ping the devices but anything on the wired lan can't.

If I try and setup ICS it wants to put everything into the stupid subnet 192.168.137.0/24 which is not practical.

Is there anyway to bridge the hostednetwork and the main lan so that all the Wifi devices appear on the network and have access to the internet?

It's a shame the server has to be running windows because I could easily setup this on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I did several attempts to make it working. My wireless network connection has created 2 Virtual miniport Adapters by running active WLAN service.

1. I tried to bridge original connection to LAN interface - no luck.
2. I tried to manually setup IP addresses on miniport Adapter - no luck, I was not able to connect any wireless device like smartphone.

Also complication I have - is already bridged internet interface which excluded possibility to enable ICS.

The only way forward I see, to setup NAT on windows Server edition - Routing and Remote Access Service + DHCP Service.